# How to redirect output of multiple scripts in QTextBrowser using PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, wizard

I have used `QtDesigner` to make a Wizard and converted the `.ui` *file* using `pyuic4`.

This wizard has multiple pages. One of the pages includes checkboxes. The checkboxes are used to select certain python scripts  to be run.

My question is **how should I go about calling the selected scripts one after the other and thereafter**, redirecting the output in real-time to a `QTextBrowser` widget in any of the subsequent wizard page(s).

Finally ,while the scripts are running is there an option to temporarily disable the next and back buttons.?

Answer (score 1):

Use `QThread` to avoid UI freeze;
run scripts in the thread using `subprocess.Popen` with `stdout=PIPE`,
read their output line by line, `emit` the lines, and get them in whatever `slot` you want.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTextBrowser, QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Event

class ScriptRunner(QThread):
    # fired whenever a line from subprocess.stdout arrived
    got_line = pyqtSignal(unicode)

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.put = self.queue.put
        self.stop_event = Event()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """thread function"""
        while 1:
            script = self.queue.get()
            if script is None:  # no more scripts
                break
            # run the script
            proc = Popen(script,  bufsize=1, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, 
                         universal_newlines=True)
            # read its output line by line
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                line = proc.stdout.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                self.got_line.emit(line)

    def join(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.put(None)
        self.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    text_browser = QTextBrowser()
    text_browser.show()

    runner = ScriptRunner()
    # connect to got_line signal
    runner.got_line.connect(text_browser.insertPlainText)

    # schedule a script
    runner.put('''python -c "for i in range(25): print 'dada'; import time; time.sleep(.25)"''')
    # now force python to flush its stdout; note -u switch
    runner.put('''python -uc "for i in range(25): print 'haha'; import time; time.sleep(.25)"''')

    app.exec_()
    runner.join()
```

Note however that due to buffering the output of the scripts may come in big chunks,
making it difficult to achieve the realtime smoothness like in terminal.
With python you can circumvent this by passing `-u` switch to the interpreter (not to the script).